Catch "nodes" interactions at RequestResponse level (K8s Audit Policy)
Do I get it right? When it says "nodes" interactions it means the resource nodes right? and not system:nodes?
And the rule would look like in my
audit-policy.yaml
...
- rules:
  - level: RequestResponse
    resources:
      - group: ""
        resources: ["nodes"]


The node interactions in Kubernetes audit policies are involved with the activities of the cluster nodes.
To answer your question. Yes, it is right when it says node interactions then it means the resources : [“nodes”] only. Not system:nodes.
Generally there are several audit level stages available for kubernetes audit policy as stated below :

RequestReceived

ResponseStarted

ResponseComplete

Panic


Each stage will follow the events which are triggered by Kubernetes audit policy. Check this official Kubernetes document on Auditing for more detailed information.
Check this official GKE document on Audit policy for a more detailed explanation of Kubernetes audit policy along with examples.
